# Build library archive with undefined references

Tags: gcc, linker, archive

A colleague of mine told me yesterday that building libfoo.a doesn't require all it's functions to be defined, as long as they will be if you are building an executable that links to it AND that defines that missing reference..

He said that archives are only a collection of object files with indexing, and since object files can be build with undefined references, so can archives..

Is this true ? If so, does this imply that reference resolving is ONLY performed during the linking stage (ie never at compilation or archiving) ?

Thanks a lot.. compiler is gcc by the way, language is c/c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all that is perfectly true. You seem to know that `libfoo.a`
is an `ar` archive. [`ar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) is the GNU
general purpose archiver. It is quite as happy to archive the contents
of your Documents, Pictures and/or Music folders as a collection of object
files.

External symbol resolution is linkage: it is the core business of linkage, and linkage
is done only by the linker. If `ar` were to supposed to resolve the  external symbol references of object files in an archive, then `ar`,
like the linker, would require command options to specify the external libraries in
which symbol definitions are to be searched for, and the directories in which
those libraries are to be searched for. It hasn't any.

An `ar` archive may be used as a linker input file. In this case the linker will
search in the archive for any object files that provide definitions for unresolved
symbol references that have accrued from object files already consumed. It will
not care at all what other kinds of files are in the archive, with or
without object files. If it finds any object files that define unresolved references, it extracts
them from the archive and adds them to linkage, exactly as if they had been individually
specified in the commandline and the archive not mentioned at all. So the only role of
an archive in linkage is as a bag of object files from which the linker can pick ones
it needs to carry on.

If we know the right bag to offer the linker, we're spared the difficulty of knowing
exactly which object files within in it the linkage will need. That's the usefulness
of static libraries. In principle, any archive format might have been adopted (`.tar`, `.gz`...) But `ar` was first in
the field, is not burdened with unwanted functionality (directory serialization, compression ...), and was history's choice.
Microsoft `LIB` format, incidentally, is the same as `ar` format.

For this role in the service of the linker, GNU `ar` has specialized a little
for the presence of object files. The `s` option - which is a default, overrideable by
`S` - adds a fake "file" to the archive with an empty filename and data that the
linker is able to read as a lookup table from the global symbols defined by any object files in the archive to
the names and positions of those object files. Formerly
(and in non-GNU variants of `ar`) this kludge was applied by running a separate
program, [`ranlib`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ranlib.1.html) on an archive to make it accessible to the linker.
The injection of a ranlib table is what enables the linker to pick the object files it needs out of the archive.
Any undefined references that are brought in with these object files are for the linker to
resolve as usual, from object files or libraries subsequently consumed.

The wording of your question suggests you may be under the impression that "archiving" -
e.g. creating `libfoo.a` - is one of processes that can be invoked, like compilation
and linkage, through the GCC frontends (`gcc`, `g++`, `gfortran`, etc.) This isn't
so. Those frontends invoke only (one or more of) a preprocessor, a compiler, an assembler
and the linker. Archives are an auxiliary convenience for delivering object files
to the linker and are created straightforwardly with `ar`:

```
    ar cr libfoo.a file.o...
```

When this is done, the undefined references within `libfoo.a` are exactly the
undefined references within `file.o ...`.

Comment: That's such a good answer. To add a little, the order at the linking stage makes difference to what linker picks from the archives. If you do ```g++ -lmylib -o a.out main.o``` instead of ```g++ main.o -lmylib -o a.out```, you end up with ```undefined reference``` errors as the linker chucks away the symbol information before it gets to processing ```main.o```. With the latter though, as main.o is parsed first, linker knows what symbols to look for in the provided ```.a```/```.so``` files. At least, AFAIU.